# Lagrange reduction $x^2+y^2+z^2+4xz=1$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

$$x^2+y^2+z^2+4xz=1$$
The question is reduce the equation to it's canonical shape using isometric transformations, I'm more interested in a more general solution then simply for this particular equation.

We used a symmetric matrix of coefficients $A$ then $X^TAX$ is the quadratic form(?) but I don't understand what are we supposed to do next and why (I've tried googling and found Lagrange reduction but I couldn't find explanations).

In this particular example from my calculations $X=\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y \\ z \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$ and $A=\begin{pmatrix}1 &0 &2 &0 \\ 0 &1 &0 &0 \\ 2 &0 &1 &0 \\ 0 &0 &0 &-1\end{pmatrix}$.

Answer (score 1):

Rotate $\frac{\pi}{4}$ around $y-$axis using the matrix
$$A=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
Result should be $x^2-y^2-3 z^2+1=0$